# how to run sencha touch code in eclipse

Tags: eclipse, html, ide, sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2

I am about to step into a new domain named "sencha touch 2.0".I am not familiar with this . Earlier I had used "Eclipse" IDE for creating web pages.I tried to use the same for creating html pages using sencha framework but it doesn't seem to work.I have searched a lot on the internet about how to run a web page which has sencha touch framework on eclipse but did not find antyhing that would help me.So please can someone tell me how do i use eclipse to run sencha touch code.Any help is really appreciated ,thanks.

Answer (score 1):

what exactly you mean when you say you want to run sencha touch on Eclipse ? Eclipse use inbuilt browser to run webpages, sencha touch only works with webkit browsers and Eclipse uses mozilla'a as inbuilt rendering engine. That's why you can't see the UI in Eclipse. you can open that page in Chrome and it ll work fine.